# Virtual Hosts In Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2003

I don't have a domain name for my server yet but do for one of my sites that I will host there. If you navigate to the site via the IP address I want you to go to D:\Apache . If you go to the server via mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com I want you to go to D:\Apache\mydomain. How would I do this using apache?

Answer (score 1):

You should use name based virtual hosting 
It defines sites, using Host header defined in HTTP/1.1 spec. 
Example confing

```
 NameVirtualHost *:80 
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example.com 
   DocumentRoot D:\example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.example.com 
  DocumentRoot D:\example.com\example
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The File may look something like this.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>

       ServerAdmin my@emailaddy.com
       ServerName  whateverdomain.com
       DocumentRoot D:\Apache

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>

       ServerAdmin my@emailaddy.com
       ServerName  www.mydomain.com 

       # Indexes + Directory Root.
       DirectoryIndex index.php (assuming its PHP)
       DocumentRoot D:\Apache\mydomain

</VirtualHost>
```

Then Restart Apache

```
apache -w -n "Apache" -k restart
```

If you have issues with resoving names, then edit your hosts file

```
C:\WINNT\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```